# minValue attribute in inputNumber not working in JSF primefaces?

Tags: web, jakarta-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2

The inputNumber declaration below will not accept any input, however when I removed the minValue attribute, it accept input.
What am not doing wrong here?

code xhtml:

```xml
<a:column>
  <p:inputNumber id="year"
                 value="#{consomationControleur.myYear}"
                 maxValue="#{now.year + 1900}"
                 minValue="2000"
  >
    <p:ajax event="blur" process="@this"/>
  </p:inputNumber>
</a:column>
```

java  CDI bean

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Named("consomationControleur")
@ViewScoped

public class ConsomationControleur implements Serializable {
   private int myYear;
   //...
}
```

jsf version 2.2  primefaces version 11

I tried to remove the maximum value.
I tried to set minValue to a negative value, it works, but I need the years 1990-2022. So I only need positive values.

Comment: Tried using `f:validateLongRange` on it?

Comment: `value="#{consomationControleur.myYear}"` should be changed to `value="#{consomationSiteRapportingControleur.myYear}"`

Comment: @PeterSmith( Jasper de Vries )    it's work Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would like to make a note**
 `minValue="1980" maxValue="#{now.year + 1900}"` it works but because of JS
but because of JS When you write a value, you selected the input and you type a number (like 2), the JS triter this value, and as the minimum condition is 1980, automate re update the input and put the field to minimum value 1980.
to work you have to select only the 3rd number (8) and change it, change a number by one, it's bad, but it works like this .

or you using `<f:validateLongRange minimum = "" maximum = "" />`

`<p:inputNumber   value="#{consomationControleur.anneeActuel}" >`
 `<f:validateLongRange minimum = "1900" maximum = "#{now.year + 1900}" />`
`<p:ajax event="blur" update="display2"  process="@this"/> </p:inputNumber>`